Is git merge something like retrofit?
two branches have the same file with content:
//Branch 1
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

//Branch 2
Line 1
Line A
Line B

when I am trying to merge I am unable to do:
Line 1
Line A
Line B
Line 2
Line 3

I am trying to do something like what a retrofit software does - is it possible?

What is "a retrofit software"? The only way to get your desired result is to tell the merge explicitly what you want; there are several options for what you could want: replace 2 and 3 with A and B, make A and B the last two lines, or keep A and B immediately after 1 like you actually want.

Do the merge, Git won't have any confidence in its guess at what the result should look like so you tell it: add the right result and commit.

Assuming you've changed the same block of code in both branches, Git cannot guess your intention. The result will be a merge conflict. This is not an error.
Git will leave conflict markers in your code and expects you to resolve the conflict and finish the commit. They will look something like this.
<<<<<<< HEAD
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
=======
Line 1
Line A
Line B
>>>>>>> branch2

You'd then replace this with whatever you like, add, and commit.
Line 1
Line A
Line B
Line 2
Line 3

Think of a merge conflict like a co-worker being halfway through an edit, getting confused, and handing it to you to finish.
See Basic Branching and Merging for more about the merge process.

"Because you've changed the same block of code in both branches" How do you know? The OP has not told us what the merge base looks like. (The OP seems not to know about the merge base at all.) If one side of the merge is identical to the merge base, there will be no conflict and no opportunity for manual intervention. It seems to me there's no basis for answering at all — except guessing.

@matt If my assumption was wrong, they can let me know. Answers can be conversations.

Yeah, I tend to err on the side of caution on things like this. Personally, FWIW, I would be happier if your answer started "Assuming" rather than "Because". The assumption is probably right; I don't deny that. But the OP is so clearly clueless about what a git merge is, that I worry about the OP doing the merge, not getting a merge conflict, and then not having a clue what to do next.

@matt That's a good suggestion. I've made the assumption clear. If they don't get a conflict, hopefully they'll leave a comment.
